# RxJS Observable that polls until the condition is true

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Here's legacy promise-based piece of code that works as expected and results in completed observable when the condition (the presence of global variable) is fulfilled:

```
const fooPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (window.foo) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      resolve(window.foo);
    }
  }, 100);
});

setTimeout(() => {
    window.foo = {};
}, 1000)

const foo$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fooPromise);

foo$.subscribe(
    () => console.log('success'),
    () => console.log('error'),
    () => console.log('complete')
);
```

I'm trying to convert it to neater observable-only solution, a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po8gzu3o/):

```
'use strict';

setTimeout(() => {
    window.foo = {};
}, 1000)

const foo$ = Rx.Observable.interval(100).map(() => foo).retry(-1)

foo$.subscribe(
    () => console.log('success'),
    () => console.log('error'),
    () => console.log('complete')
);
```

It looks like I'm on the right track, but the observable isn't completed and continues spamming with values.

What's the appropriate way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to take one `foo`, so use [`take(count)` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take) :

> Emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable.
>
> Takes the first count values from the source, then completes.

```
const foo$ = Rx.Observable.interval(100).map(() => foo).retry().take(1)
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stn5amky/)

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking how to unsubscribe from interval, while it was right under my nose.

Comment: I would suggest to use `filter(() => window.foo)` instead of erroring and `retry` until infinity. This is more performand and a better practice because the error is preventable (even *expected*)

Comment: I agree with that, i would have done this way. But didn't noticed it was`window.foo` and not just `foo`.